# grpc Google login failure

Tags: c++, speech, grpc

I'am trying to create a application using the cloud speech api of google.
I cloned all the repositories and created a really simple client app in C++.

```
#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>
#include "google/cloud/speech/v1/cloud_speech.grpc.pb.h"
namespace gs=google::cloud::speech::v1;
using gs::Speech;
using gs::RecognizeResponse;
using gs::RecognizeRequest;
using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::Status;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try{
        auto channel_creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();
        auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("speech.googleapis.com:443", channel_creds);
        auto stub = Speech::NewStub(channel);

        RecognizeResponse res;
        RecognizeRequest req;
        ClientContext ctx;

        auto status = stub->Recognize(&ctx, req, &res);
        if(status.ok())
        {
            std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << status.error_code() << ": " << status.error_message() << std::endl;
        }
    }catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

This compiles fine, but when executed results in the following error message:

> 16: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

I have created a Service account and placed it's json key file next to the env variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" to the correct file and I'm quite sure it is read (because if I remove it, it just crashes).
I also have enabled the speech API online.
I'm out of ideas since no matter what I do I can't get it to work.
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trying and reading some more example code I finally found the reason myself.
I had to use a different URL. Changing "speech.googleapis.com:443" to "speech.googleapis.com" results in a different error, but connection and login work.

Setting up all parameters for this function correctly and supplying actual audio data returns usable results. I did not expect the port to make a difference, considering both URLs are in many example programs and grpc uses http2 (which in turn uses port 443).

**Important piece: Make sure you don't include a port for use with google services.**